# Hide <div> with HTML, show with CSS

Tags: html, css, show-hide

Admittedly, this is more out of curiosity than any practical relevance, but I trying to address the case when a browser has disabled CSS.

I have a `<div>` containing a `<svg>` but that element makes little sense without some CSS magic. Is there any way I could hide it with plain HTML which could be undone for browsers which allow CSS?

My best option right now is

```
<div><svg width="0" height="0"></svg></div>
```

which leaves an "empty" `<div>` with `lineheight: 1`.

Answer (score -1):

If CSS isn't allowed, I would detach de DOM element through JS.

Comment: The question is how would they know.

Comment: Ops, sorry, well, in that case I would test something like establishing a width (for example) with CSS and then testing if there's a correspondence between that stablished value and the one obtained with `getComputedStyle()`.